# Parameters is transfered to new url when redirected in .hcaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have a tube site, where I want some searches to be redirected to a new url..

The problem is, that parameters is transfered to the redirected URL with unexpected results.

Its an adult tube website, so is not safe for work.

But if I search for a model named Marsha May, the normal result page is /search/marsha-may

But I want the result page to be https://www.triplx.dk/models/marsha-may-22.html

So I created a 301 redirect

Redirect 301 /search/marsha-may/ https://www.triplx.dk/models/marsha-may-22.html

But when I do the search, I end up at

https://www.triplx.dk/models/marsha-may-22.html?controller=index&mode=search&q=marsha-may&page=1

where the paramters are the search parameters that is transfered to the new url. How do I easily strip those parameters?

Comment: There is nothing in that redirection rule that is responsible for adding those parameters. Either you are looking at cached results or, more likely, you have some logic implemented besides that rule which adds the parameters. Most likely your search logic itself creates such output.

Comment: These URL parameters presumably are what the request gets rewritten to internally, so this looks like you have somehow created a situation where both happen “in one go”, your external redirect and the internal one get mixed together. We’d have to see the rest of your URL rewriting, to be able to determine what is going on.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0cwWZWFF

The entire hcaccess is there.